# Best api for generating graph

Tags: jquery, graph

I want to generate graph from my database data can anyone tell me about which type of graph is

more suitable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try out these i think this is the best options for you..

```
http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/

http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Google Chart API:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 0):

jqplot ([http://www.jqplot.com](http://www.jqplot.com/)) is an interesting jquery plugin that can generate many data related graphs.